# I want to remove duplicate objects by name property by I am getting No overload matches this call in rxjs

Tags: rxjs

```
 allEmployees$ = this.http.get<IEmployees[]>('../../assets/employees').pipe(
    map(allEmployees => 
      allEmployees.map(Employee =>       
        <IEmployees>({
        id: Employee.id,
        name: Employee.name,
        email: Employee.email,
        gender: Employee.gender,
        productid: Employee.productid,
        productName: 'N/A',
      })
    )),
    switchMap(data => data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      const exists = acc.find(v => v['name'] === curr['name']);
      return exists ? acc : acc.concat(curr);
    }, []))
  );
```

Please see pic for more info:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the Typescript compiler is having trouble inferring the type of the array in the seed parameter of `reduce`. Try casting it to `IEmployees[]`